# Moving UIButton from UIScrollView to UIView in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

I am stuck with a problem actually the scene is like this in my view controller i have place several buttons which i can move within the view now in same view half of the screens is occupied by uiscrollview in this scrollview also i have several uibuttons which i want to move from uiscrollview to uiview Now when i try to move uibutton from uiscrollview to uiview it hides as it moves from the scrollview similarly as i move uibutton from uiview to uiscrollview then also it hides as my drag reaches the scrollview area.

Please help me out with this problem

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Your UIButtons each have a superview. For the UIButtons in the scrollview, the UIScrollView is the superview. When you have scrollView.clipsToBounds == YES, then the UIButtons in the scrollview will become obscured if you move them outside of the visible area of the scrollview.

There are several possible solutions, including:

1. Add code to change the superview of the UIButtons once they reach the edge of the scrollview (but this is tricky, and I wouldn't do it unless there was an easier option, check out [Apple's UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html), especially (UIView)removeFromSuperview and (UIView)addSubview:). You would have to perform this switch of superview in the code that moves the button (or tracks the move).
2. Add the UIButtons to a UIView which is the parent of the scrollview, maybe even your viewcontroller.view (but your UIButtons in the scrollview will no longer move with the scrollview upon scrolling). You would add the buttons to the view **behind** the scrollview, but so that they show **above** it.

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestions i will look into the First Solution as the second solution doesn't seems to fit my requirement.